# Is it possible to use SDL2 with -nostartfiles?

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been tinkering with `SDL` for the past few days and I've attempted to use remove main by using flags `--nostartfiles` and `--entry _start` on a project using `SDL` to reduce size. However, upon running the program, I get a segfault on any `SDL` command. The code works without these parameters with _start renamed to main.

Is it possible to remove main?

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" void _start()
{

  SDL_Window* Window = SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0);
  SDL_GL_CreateContext(Window);

  while (1) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
      switch (event.type) {
      case SDL_QUIT:
        exit(1);
        break;
      }
    }
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(Window);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

I have a callstack [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Cba.png)

I'm using Linux and C++ if that helps.

Comment: Do you have a call stack if you inspect the core dump (or have gdb attached when sigsegv is raised)?

Comment: I'll check in a second and mod the post appropriately

Comment: You probably need to add [`SDL_SetMainReady();`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetMainReady) and `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);`/`SDL_Quit();` inside the `_start()` function.

Comment: Segfault still exists after putting those in

Comment: "*I've attempted to use remove main*" -- what? Understand when you create a library of SDL routines (or just a set of functions and a header for that matter) -- there is no need to include a main to begin with. The compiler and linker know in both cases (compiling a shared-library or object file) what files are needed. The SDL library you are using may well have been compiled expecting the normal startupfiles are present in what you use with it.

Comment: Are you trying to create a demo and have some size limit you need to stay within? Otherwise I don't see why you would want to do this.